# Query only unique rows in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Table Like this:

```
 Serial      IO
----------------------------------------------------
    1       i
    2       i
    3       i
    1       o
```

Expected result : all serial that has no `o` in `IO` column

```
 Serial      IO
-----------------------------------------------------
    2       i
    3       i
```

for example Serial `1` has both `i` and `o` in `IO` Column, that's why it doesn't appear in result pane.

Comment: What's the important feature here?  `unique` or `has no 'o' in IO column`?  Could a serial have `i` more than once, and so be excluded as it's not unique?  Could a serial only appear once, with an IO of `o`, and so be unique, and so be included?  etc, etc...

Comment: Could a serial have i more than once ? No, It's unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select serial, io
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.serial = t.serial and t2.io = 'o');
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a way:

```
WITH i_table AS (SELECT serial,IO FROM my_table WHERE IO = 'i'),
o_table AS (SELECT serial,IO FROM my_table WHERE IO = 'o')
SELECT DISTINCT i.* 
FROM i_table AS i 
    LEFT JOIN o_table AS o 
    ON i.serial = o.serial 
WHERE o.serial IS NULL;
```

Comment: The Op mentioned Unique rows.  Should a serial be able to have `i` more than once, this solution will stumble.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk I edited after the comment of MatBailie.

Comment: @MatBailie Right. I have fixed it.

Comment: @MatBailie a serial can only have **"I"** once for each serial. So this will work

Answer (score 2):

`NOT EXISTS` and similar approaches work.  Depending on indexes using windows/analytic functions can have different performance profiles...

```
WITH
  sized AS
(
  SELECT
    yourTable.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY IO)   AS group_size
  FROM
    yourTable
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  sized
WHERE
  group_size = 1
```

Comment: This would include any serial with a unique value for serial and not necessarily exclude those with **'O'**

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Agreed.  Which fits the title of the OP.  Having asked for clarification, even the clarification is vague/incomplete, so I'm leaving this as it is.

Comment: "all serial that has no o in IO column" is clear to me

Answer (score 2):

Try following code.

```
select t.Serial,t.IO from table1 t inner join 
(select Serial from table1 group by Serial 
having count(distinct IO) = 1) t2 ON t.Serial = t2.Serial
where t.IO != 'o'
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2a0d7/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select distinct * from MY_TABLE
where [Serial] not in (select [Serial] from MY_TABLE where [IO] = 'o')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can left join and exclude those with a match

```
SELECT
  a.Serial,
  a.[IO]
FROM <table> a
LEFT JOIN
  <table> b
ON a.Serial = b.Serial
  and b.[IO] = 'o'
WHERE
  a.[IO] = 'i' 
  and b.[IO] is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient but short

```
select Serial, io  from table where 'io' = 'i'
except 
select Serial, 'i' from table where 'io' = 'o'
```